# react-app-rewired not working with tailwind css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, tailwind-css, react-app-rewired

I have an ongoing React.js project with these react versions.

```
 "react": "^17.0.2",
 "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
```

The project is running perfectly without any issues. I wanted to add tailwind CSS for some parts of my project. So I follow all the steps in this [Official documentation guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

But tailwind is not working at all. I have noticed my npm start command is a bit different, that may be the reason. My start command is `"start": "react-app-rewired start"` Normally when you create project with create-react-app it `"start": "react-scripts start"` Is this the reason that tailwind is not working here? How can I fix this?

Any help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it by creating the Tailwind build process manually.

1. Create a `tailwind-setup.css` inside `src` folder.
2. Edit your `package.json` `script` object to this:

```
"scripts": {
    "tailwind":"npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind-setup.css -o ./src/tailwind-output.css --watch",
    "start": "react-app-rewired start & yarn run tailwind",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build & yarn run tailwind",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test & yarn run tailwind",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    ...
  },
```

3. And import `./src/tailwind-output.css` in your `App.tsx`.